# how to fix the login bugs in android studio

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I tried to use json for the login. My php returns this result:

```
[{"name":"cynthia","password":"123456"},{"name":"John","password":"123456"}]
```

These are the data in mySQL.

And I would like to use this result to have a comparison in android studio but I found that it is not working. It always goes to the else statement.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText username;
    public EditText password;
    private ArrayList<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> passwordList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    }

    public void Login2(View view) {
        if (username.getText().length() == 0 || password.getText().length() == 0) {
            openDialog(view);
        } else {
            new AsyncRetrieve().execute();
            if(usernameList.contains(username)&&passwordList.contains(password)){
                successLogin();
            }else{
                openDialog(view);
            }

        }
    }

    public void openDialog(View view) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.login_dialog_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.login_dialog_msg)
                .show();
    }

    public void successLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, HomePageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return getVideoList();
        }

        private String getVideoList() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/soften/login_check1.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String response = reader.readLine();

                //set the response from server as json array
                JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray(response);

                usernameList.clear();
                passwordList.clear();
                Log.d("username", "value = " + userArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {
                    Log.d("i", "i = " + i);
                    //get json object from the json array
                    JSONObject json = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("json", "" + json.length());
                    //add object to the list for grid view
                    usernameList.add(json.getString("name"));
                    passwordList.add(json.getString("password"));
                }



                return null;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return ex.toString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like a very insecure method unless you secure your endpoint. Downloading the details of all users from the database to a phone for the login seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

you long2() is erro m, is there

```
if(usernameList.contains(username)&&passwordList.contains(password))
```

you should equals  username.getText() and password.getText()  。My English is not very good, but you should be able to understand

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. i added .getText() now but it still not working. It seems that the arraylist doesnt contain the required strings coz when i changed the statement to    
  if(!usernameList.contains(username.getText().toString())){ 

it can enter to the next page. Do you know why? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
 new AsyncRetrieve().execute();
```

when your execute a AsyncTask it starts a background thread but immediately you proceed further without waiting for the result coming from server and when you compare username and password both these list are empty.

```
 private ArrayList<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<String>();
 private ArrayList<String> passwordList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Solution:**

First solution is to add a get() methods to your AsyncTask Call like

```
new AsyncRetrieve().execute().get();
```

it will halt your AsyncTask until the Result received from server and then did your comparison.

The other solution is to override onPostExecute() in AsyncTask and perform comparison there.

```
 private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return getVideoList();
        }

        private String getVideoList() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/soften/login_check1.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String response = reader.readLine();

                //set the response from server as json array
                JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray(response);

                usernameList.clear();
                passwordList.clear();
                Log.d("username", "value = " + userArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {
                    Log.d("i", "i = " + i);
                    //get json object from the json array
                    JSONObject json = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("json", "" + json.length());
                    //add object to the list for grid view
                    usernameList.add(json.getString("name"));
                    passwordList.add(json.getString("password"));
                }



                return null;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return ex.toString();
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected String onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(usernameList.contains(username.getText())&&passwordList.contains(password.getText())){
                successLogin();
            }else{
                openDialog(view);
            }
        }
    }
```

Remove these lines from Login2 method :) Don't forget to add getText() method.

Hope this help.